# Setup routines on macOS to mimic Samsung routines

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, applescript, automator, ventura

Is there a way, or a free tool available to create, routines on macOS just like Samsung allows to create routines?

For example, my custom Samsung routines are:

- Switch off charging when battery reaches 95%
- Shoutout "Low battery" when battery=10
- When I connect to office wifi: set speaker=30%, headphone=100%, system sound=20%
- When geo-location=home: set volume=100%, battery-optimization=false
- if video is playing, set notification sound to mute

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am looking for similar feature/tool in macOS to perform tasks like:

- Shoutout “Fully charged” if mac battery=100 and ‘low battery’ when
- battery=15 Mute the laptop speaker if my wifi=adobe
- Turn off charging if battery=95%

Comment: Which Mac? Which OS? Or don't you have a mac yet?

Comment: macbook pro, macOS Ventura 13.1

Comment: Now add that info to the question since it makes a difference to people who may help, and info left in comments can get lost.

Answer (score 2):

The closest to "Routines" is probably the Shortcuts.app. It's well worth exploring. There is an action for setting the volume. There will certainly be other ways of setting the specific values you want, like using `defaults write` commands in the Terminal.

macOS has a "Focus" feature, that lets you disable notifications and other disturbances, and you can set the Focus level in Shortcuts, too.

System Settings has an option to "Optimize Battery Charging", which will hold at 80% if you leave it plugged in for a few days. And there is a Low battery warning at some relevant level. You don't need to manually manage the battery. It's much larger than a phone's, so the tolerances and lifespan are much greater.